# Get multiple input values in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

i'm rendering an string array 'options' as this

```
<View ref={refInput}>
        {options.map((item, index) => (
          <View key={index}>
            <View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <TextInput placeholder={item}></TextInput>
              {options.length > 2 && index === options.length - 1 && (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={removeOption}>
                  <Text>Remover</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
            {index >= options.length - 1 && index < 3 && (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addOption(index)}>
                <Text>Adicionar</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
```

For each element in my array i'm rendering a text input. It starts with 2 and can go up to 4 inputs. What is the best way to get those inputs values?

I passed a ref to the first View that renders the map and i have a function that get that ref by

```
const input = refInput.current
```

It returns to me a HTML collection that's a bit complicated to iterate and i don't even know how to type it with typescript.

So is there a better way to get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the input values inside a state. Since you have multiple inputs that you generate dynamically inside a loop, we could store these states inside a state array and induce a bijection between indices and input values.

Here is one possible implementation using your initial code as a basis.

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    setValues(options.map(item => ""));
}, [options])

function handleTextChange(index, newValue) {
    setValues(prev => prev.map((val, i) => index === i ? newValue : val))
}

<View ref={refInput}>
        {options.map((item, index) => (
          <View key={index}>
            <View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <TextInput onChangeText={(newValue) => handleTextChange(index, newValue)} value={values[index]} placeholder={item}></TextInput>
              {options.length > 2 && index === options.length - 1 && (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={removeOption}>
                  <Text>Remover</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
            {index >= options.length - 1 && index < 3 && (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addOption(index)}>
                <Text>Adicionar</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
```